# How to access a list inside the same class but different method

Tags: java

I have this class called DeckPC:

```
   public class DeckPC {
    // creating 3 cards, composed of one random number from 1 to 7
    private int cardSword = (int)(Math.random() * ((7 - 1) + 1)) + 1;
    private int cardBast = (int)(Math.random() * ((7 - 1) + 1)) + 1;
    private int cardGold = (int)(Math.random() * ((7 - 1) + 1)) + 1;

    static List<Integer> DeckPC = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

    public void creatingDeck(int cardSword, int cardBast, int cardGold) {
        this.cardSword = cardSword;
        this.cardBast = cardBast;
        this.cardGold = cardGold;

        // trying to add the variables(ints) from above into the DeckPC list.
        DeckPC.add(cardSword);
        DeckPC.add(cardBast);
        DeckPC.add(cardGold);
    }

    public List<Integer> getDeckPC() {  
        return DeckPC;
    }
}
```

And then a main class with main method in which I want to call getDeckPC() so that it shows the values I have inserted into DeckPC:

```
DeckPC deckPC = new DeckPC();
deckPC.getDeckPC();
```

But the problem is that it doesnt return anything at all this way. But if I initialize the list "DeckPC"(without static) inside of the creatingDeck method, then it returns a list but empty like so: []. What am I doing wrong? Maybe using the wrong access modifier?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `creatingDeck(...)` before calling `getDeckPC()` so the list items get added to the list:

```
DeckPC deckPC = new DeckPC();
deckPC.creatingDeck(1, 2, 3); ///// ADD this line
deckPC.getDeckPC();
```

As a side note, your code will be easier to debug and avoid some very difficult-to-find bugs if the class, member variable, instantiated variable, and method don't have the same name.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't called the `creatingDeck` procedure to initialize the values of the list you have 2 choices here :

1- you could initialize the code by calling the `creatingDeck` procedure and passing some argument which won't be the good idea given that you want a random number.

2- You could use static initializer like this :

```
 public class DeckPC {
    // creating 3 cards, composed of one random number from 1 to 7
    private static int cardSword = (int)(Math.random() * ((7 - 1) + 1)) + 1;
    private static int cardBast = (int)(Math.random() * ((7 - 1) + 1)) + 1;
    private static int cardGold = (int)(Math.random() * ((7 - 1) + 1)) + 1;

    static List<Integer> DeckPC = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    static {
        DeckPC.add(cardSword);
        DeckPC.add(cardBast);
        DeckPC.add(cardGold);
      }

    public List<Integer> getDeckPC() {  
        return DeckPC;
    }
}
```

-static initializer is called the first time your program runs because in Java static variable are available all the life of your program.

-**Update :** there is also an instance initializer if you want to update the values every time you create a new instance of the class the code will be something like this :

```
 public class DeckPC {
    // creating 3 cards, composed of one random number from 1 to 7
    private int cardSword = (int)(Math.random() * ((7 - 1) + 1)) + 1;
    private int cardBast = (int)(Math.random() * ((7 - 1) + 1)) + 1;
    private int cardGold = (int)(Math.random() * ((7 - 1) + 1)) + 1;

    static List<Integer> DeckPC = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

     {
        DeckPC.add(cardSword);
        DeckPC.add(cardBast);
        DeckPC.add(cardGold);
      }

    public List<Integer> getDeckPC() {  
        return DeckPC;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should call creatingDeck method first to fill in the list, then call getDeckPC() to print it, or just

> public List getDeckPC() {
>           creatingDeck(1,2,3); // <------ call it here
>           return DeckPC;
>   }